# Hitting an exception while updating an ENTITY, using EntityEntry in .Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

Update Method:

```
void IExpenseService.Update(Expense expenseItem)
    {

        //Create an Entity Entry object.
        var expense = context.Entry(expenseItem);
        if (expense != null)
        {

            if (expense.State!=EntityState.Detached)
            {
                _context.Attach(expenseItem);
            }
            expense.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The instance of entity type 'Expense' cannot be tracked because another instance 
  of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities,
  for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. 
  if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly 
  setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities 
  or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, 
  ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Func`2 handleNode)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
```

Comment: Did you get the expenseItem from EF? Maybe you wanted to attach  expense and not expenseItem?

Comment: **_"The instance of entity type 'Expense' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked"_** seems pretty clear

Comment: It seem you try to attach your entity if.... it's *not* detached, so it create a duplicate in entity's eyes, with 2 object with the same ID.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but if I look at your code the line `if (expense.State!=EntityState.Detached)` should be `if (expense.State==EntityState.Detached)` as you can attach an element only if it's detached.

Comment: if (expense.State!=EntityState.Detached)
            {
                _context.Attach(expenseItem);
            } why do you not check if the state IS detached? and if it is, maybe you should attach expense, not expenseItem.

Comment: After changing to (expense.State == EntityState.Detached),
still the Exception is thrown.